# Django-superform does not render

Tags: python, django

**My spec:**

Django 1.9
Python 3.5.1
django-superform 0.3.1

**My goal:**
I want `bod_quota` form nested with `CustomerForm`

**My attempt**

I have follow the docs https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-superform
But it does not rendered nested form.
`customer/model.py`

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    name_th = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name_en = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

`customer/forms.py`

```
class CustomerForm(SuperModelForm):
    manual_quota = InlineFormSetField(parent_model=Customer, model=BodQuota, fields = (
            "quota_per_occurrence_type",
            "quota_by_month",
            "quota_by_year",
            "quota_count_method_type",
        ) )

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = [
            'customer_code',
            'name_th',
            'name_en',
        ]
```

`bod_quota/model.py`

```
class BodQuota(models.Model):
    #
    # Change Quota General Types
    #
    class QuotaPerOccurrenceType(DjangoChoices):
        monthly = ChoiceItem('monthly')
        yearly = ChoiceItem('yearly')

    class QuotaCountMethodType(DjangoChoices):
        circuit_based = ChoiceItem('circuit_based')
        customer_based = ChoiceItem('customer_based')

    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, default=None)
    quota_per_occurrence_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        choices=QuotaPerOccurrenceType.choices,
        validators=[QuotaPerOccurrenceType.validator],
        default=QuotaPerOccurrenceType.monthly)
    quota_by_month = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        null=False, blank=False, default=0, help_text=_("monthly quota"))
    quota_by_year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        null=False, blank=False, default=0, help_text=_("annually quota"))
    quota_count_method_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        choices=QuotaCountMethodType.choices,
        validators=[QuotaCountMethodType.validator],
        default=QuotaCountMethodType.customer_based)
```

`bod_quota/forms.py`

```
class BodQuotaForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BodQuota
        fields = (
            "quota_per_occurrence_type",
            "quota_by_month",
            "quota_by_year",
            "quota_count_method_type",
        )


BodQuotaFormSet = modelformset_factory(BodQuota, form=BodQuotaForm)
```

**Problem:**
`manual_quota` does not show in the browser

Comment: hi, Please don't forget to add (s) here customer/form(--s--).py, so django can recognize it as form.

Comment: I have typo in my post thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There’s two way to show this in the browser.

```
•   views methods: I think it’s well explained here
```

http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/

```
•   django admin interface
```

Personally, I’m used to start by the django admin interface in a first approach.

Based in you example, I can reproduce the forms below.

In case, it’s what you looking for, please check that:

1.You have this in your setting.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #TESTING DJANGO SUPER_FORM_PCKG
    'django_superform',
    'customer',
    'djchoices',
    'bod_quota’,
    #DEFAULT DJANGO SETTING   
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

2.In your file admin.py under customer app folder, add the code below

```
from django.contrib import admin
from customer.models import *
admin.autodiscover()
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('customer_code', 'name_th','name_en')
admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

## In the interface you will have the form below

[image]

3.In your file admin.py under bod_quota app folder, add the code below

```
from customer.forms import *
admin.autodiscover()
class BodQuotaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields  = [ 'customer','quota_per_occurrence_type','quota_by_month','quota_by_year','quota_count_method_type']
    form    = CustomerForm
admin.site.register(BodQuota, BodQuotaAdmin)
```

## In the interface you will have the form below

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it does not help because I want that `bod_quota` attach to the `customer` form like it is not come from another app. I know admin interface and I am not going to let customer use that way.